# Is there a way to ignore a class with the <noscript> tag?

Tags: javascript, css, class

I'm currently using wow.js in order to fade in content as you scroll down. The way it works is you add the div class `wow` to something you'd like to fade in, which the wow.js recognizes and then animates. (Really simple documentation here http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/docs.html)

However, if the browser has javascript disabled, it fails to recognize any css styling on anything with the class `wow`, as `.wow` is not defined in my stylesheet. I'm wondering if there is a workaround to this - should I add the `.wow` class to my own stylesheet as well, with something like `.wow {display: block}`? Or is there a way to tell a browser with no javascript enabled to simply ignore the `wow` class?

Unfortunately I cannot simply put a `<noscript>`message saying javascript is disabled, as I know many people at work will be viewing the site, where javascript is disabled, and they need to be able to view it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The common way to do this is the other way around. I'm not sure if the library is limiting, but you can add a class to the `<html>` or `<body>` element identifying that JS is available. The way to do that in reverse would be to have a class like `.no-js`, and then remove it from the `<body>` if JS can run.

For example

```
<body class="no-js">
    <script type="text/javascript">document.body.className = "";</script>
```

From there, in your CSS, simply do the following:

```
.no-js .wow {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Would `.no-js` be partnered with Modernizr?

Comment: You can do use it with Modernizr, and it will automatically strip the class from it so you don't have to. But if you do that, you'll want to put it on the `<html>` element I believe

Answer (score 1):

How about you only add the `wow` class if the browser does have Javascript?

For example:

```
<div id="one" class="wowable"></div>
<div id="two" class="wowable"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var wowables = document.getElementsByClassName('wowable');
    for(var i = 0; i < wowables.length; i++) {
        wowables[i].classList.remove( 'wowable' );
        wowables[i].classList.add( 'wow' );
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I think you might have forgot to

Comment: Some people forget to finish what they

Comment: finish typing your post.

Comment: Well, in your question, you wrote `wow {display: block}`, just use `wowable {display: block}`.